# How to convert nuget package/ C# code to dart pub package?

Tags: flutter, c#-4.0, nuget-package, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Background : I have few nuget packages (C# repo) and i am trying to access those in Flutter Dart code.

Is there any option we can consume nuget/c# code in Flutter dart pub package?